# NVCC multiple definitions when linking object files

Tags: c++, include, g++, linker-errors, nvcc

I am using a library (stb_image) that consists of 2 header files I downloaded from the internet.

I am compiling with nvcc (I'm pretty sure I'd get the same errors using g++), and since its super slow, I am compiling each .cu file into a .o file and then linking them together.

Excerpt of my Makefile:

```
./bin/filter: $(object_files) $(h_files)
    nvcc $(object_files) -o ./bin/filter

./bin/%.o : %.cu
    nvcc -dc $< -o $@

./bin/%.o : %.cpp
    nvcc -dc $< -o $@
```

I have two .cu files that include `image.h`. `image.h` includes the two library files as well as defines a few extra methods in a namespace.

main.cu:

```
#include "filter.h"
#include "image.h"
#include "apply.h"
...
```

apply.cu:

```
#include "filter.h"
#include "image.h"
#include "apply.h"
...
```

image.h:

```
#ifndef IMAGE_H
#define IMAGE_H

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {
    #define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
    #define STB_IMAGE_WRITE_IMPLEMENTATION
    #include "stb_image.h"
    #include "stb_image_write.h"
}

using namespace std;

struct Pixel {
    ...
};

struct Image {
    ...
};

namespace ImageIO {
    Image loadImage(char* filename) {
        ...
    }

    void writeImage(char* filename, Image &image) {
        ...
    }
};
#endif
```

The output of `make ./bin/filter` is:

```
nvcc -dc main.cu -o bin/main.o
nvcc -dc apply.cu -o bin/apply.o
nvcc ./bin/main.o ./bin/apply.o -o ./bin/filter
./bin/apply.o: In function `stbi_failure_reason':
tmpxft_00008553_00000000-5_apply.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x201): multiple definition of `stbi_failure_reason'
./bin/main.o:tmpxft_00008532_00000000-5_main.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x201): first defined here
...
```

It goes on to give a multiple definitions error for every single function defined in the library headers and also `ImageIO::writeImage` and `ImageIO::loadImage`.

I think what's happening is the definitions from the header files are being included in both `bin/main.o` and `bin/apply.o`, so when they're linked together there are 2 definitions of each included function.

I would prefer if I didn't have to reformat the library headers to use their own .cpp files as that would be a lot of work. Is there anyway to fix this issue without moving the function definitions out of the header files?

Comment: renaming the .cu files to .cpp and running `g++ main.cpp apply.cpp -o ./bin/filter` gives the same error.

Comment: You could declare them `inline`. But I think the better solution would be to move them.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a workaround. Since I only need the library files in the image.h functions, I made an image.cpp and import the library files exclusively in image.cpp. That way they are included in only image.o and none of the other .o files.